# Implicit Controllers In Rails

Tags: laravel, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, routes, url-routing

Does Ruby On Rails has implicit controllers, just like [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/controllers#implicit-controllers) has?

I was reading the rails [routing documentation](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html), but didn't find it.

Is there any way to create it?

Comment: AFAIK, no! Every route handles only one action.

Comment: It does support resource/restful controllers though.

Comment: I didn't use rails to much, but http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html

Comment: I've used Rails quite extensively but I have not seen implicit routes like in Laravel. There may be a gem out there that let's you do something similar though.